# SSIS - Continue Package Flow even after inner task in a Foreach Loop Container fails

Tags: ssis

In the figure below, why is the Foreach Loop Container failing *despite* the fail path (of the DFT that failed) being handled correctly?

**How can I get the loop to continue after handling fail path?**

[image]

If it helps to know what's going on in the package, here's the gist:

> We have a requirement where data from Excel files must be loaded into
>   a DB. The package we have splits each Excel file into constituent CSV
>   files (one CSV per sheet), and loads the CSVs into the DB. It is
>   possible that some of the sheets have issues (missing columns, data
>   type mismatch etc), and such erroneous CSVs are captured by the fail
>   path of the DFT. Ideally the package must resume processing the rest
>   of the CSVs, and the rest of the Excel files, and exit successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have any **OnError** EventHandlers defined for that Data Flow Task? If yes, you could as well set the System Variable, **Propogate** (type Boolean), for that Error Handler scope to **'False'**.

Also please go through [Gracefully Handing Task Error in SSIS Package](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rushabh_mehta/archive/2008/04/24/gracefully-handing-task-error-in-ssis-package.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing, thanks to [SSIS Foreach Loop Container: Continue on Error](http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.in/2010/12/ssis-foreach-loop-container-continue-on.html). I was going to answer my own question with a screenshot, but you beat me to it! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There is a property on every SSIS component that is called `MaximumErrorCount` which defines the number of errors that this particular component can accept before failing the whole package.

You have to increase this value for each and every component that you want to continue executing before failing.