# Where to put the error handler within a package

Tags: ssis

Similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414648/ssis-continue-package-flow-even-after-inner-task-in-a-foreach-loop-container-f), but in my case, I want anything within the "ForEach Orders" to NOT cause the package to fail, but rather continue on to the next order.  So, in the picture below, if the SQL task "Get Lines for Order" fails or anything else within the "ForEach for Orders" has an error, the flow should continue on to the next order.  Id rather not have to set an event handler on each task within this level.

So possibly put both wrap both the "Get Lines for Order" and "ForEach for OrderLines" within a sequence container, then put an OnError handler on that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the package to process all elements within the foreach loop enumerator; if failures occur, keep going.

If this is the case, there is a simpler solution. Click on the foreach loop in question. In the properties box, you will see MaximumErrorCount. Set the value to 0. This will run through all items in the loop, regardless of fail count.

Note: You can still add an OnError event handler to perform some task in the event there is an error. But, the package will continue to execute the foreach loop after that.